# Get error integation of dropcam library in the xcode

Tags: ios, rtsp

I am new in the iPhone app development, I wants to do live streaming in the iPhone through my app. Please suggest me how to develop video streaming in the iPhone/iPad. Current, I am integrate dropcam library for rtsp video streaming in the iPhone, but after integration of the Live555, DecoderWrapper, ffmpeg and libswscale library in my project, I have get 15 error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_av_register_all", referenced from:
      +[VideoDecoder staticInitialize] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_init", referenced from:
      +[VideoDecoder staticInitialize] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_av_log_set_callback", referenced from:
      +[VideoDecoder registerLogCallback:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_find_decoder", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder initWithCodec:colorSpace:width:height:privateData:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_alloc_context", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder initWithCodec:colorSpace:width:height:privateData:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_av_malloc", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder initWithCodec:colorSpace:width:height:privateData:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
      -[VideoDecoder decodeFrame:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_alloc_frame", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder initWithCodec:colorSpace:width:height:privateData:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_open", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder initWithCodec:colorSpace:width:height:privateData:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_decode_video2", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder decodeFrame:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avpicture_get_size", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder decodeFrame:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avpicture_fill", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder decodeFrame:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder decodeFrame:] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder getDecodedFrame] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder dealloc] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
  "_avcodec_close", referenced from:
      -[VideoDecoder dealloc] in libDecoderWrapper.a(VideoDecoder.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me to resolve these error or please tell me how to work video streaming in the iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project > Build Phases > expand Compile Sources > press + > add libDecoderWrapper.m

Alternatively remove the library and re add it to Xcode while making sure the "Add to targets" checkbox is checked to automatically add all to the compile sources phase, there is a bug with Xcode 4.3 that makes that checkbox to be unchecked.

Comment: thanks for reply but when i select my project > build phases > press + > then i have get list of framework and libDropcam.a library. so how to add libDecoderWrapper.m file. please suggest me.